# Why is my pandas profile report saving in my root directory?

Tags: python, pandas, working-directory, pandas-profiling

```
def get_profile(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, file_name: str ="Pandas Profiling Report", show: bool = False):

dataframe_profile = ProfileReport(dataframe, title= file_name)
dataframe_profile.to_file(file_name)
if show:
    dataframe_profile.to_notebook_iframe()
```

Hi all,

I am trying to add this simple function to my code that allows the user to download a copy of their pandas profile report however the person who is testing it says that the file goes to their root directory rather than their working directory. Is there a way that I can change that? Can't find in documentation or elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

The file name needs to [include the file extension](https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling#:%7E:text=profile.to_file(%22your_report.html%22)) as well. Therefore, `str = "Pandas Profiling Report.html"` should work.